# PostgreSQL unnest, WHERE clause on specific element of nested field

Tags: postgresql, nested, unnest

Given the table below, I'd like to pull the `id` value WHERE 60 appears as the second element of `status`. I see that it's a nested field. Within that, how would I get the to the second element?

```
╔════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id │ status                                         ║
╠════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  │  {"(1234,60,\"2020-02-29 01:18:19.309232\")"}  ║
╟────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 2  │  {"(4567,70,\"2020-02-29 01:18:19.309232\")"}  ║
╚════╧════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The result should be `id = 1` because 60 is the second element of `status` for that row.

My colleague told me about the different fields within the value.

1. `user_id` (`bigint`)
2. `status` (`bigint`)
3. `updated_at` (`timestamp`)

Comment: "*I see that it's a nested field.*" - what exactly is its data type? It doesn't look like an array, it doesn't look like JSON, it's more like a custom string format.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what type it is. It's called "user_status_t[]". Not sure what type that is.

Comment: Ah well that's a big difference! `user_status_t` would be a [custom composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rowtypes.html). Please show us its definition in your schema.

Comment: Thanks! My colleague told me about the different fields within the value.

1st - user_id (bigint),
2nd - status (bigint),
3rd - updated_at (timestamp)

Using the documentation you showed me, I know how to access it now. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then

Answer (score 0):

You can access the individual elements of a composite type with `.`. So the query to your (denormalized!) table would be

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name
WHERE (table_name.status).status = 60;
```